# Shell script test

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I'm tring to update a bash script written by someone else and I've come accross a line I'm not sure about.

Can anyone tell me what the following check does:

```
if [ :$RESULT != :0,0 ]
```

I assume it's checking for some value in $RESULT, possibly with a substring?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 13):

The command `[` is just an alias of the command `test`, the closing square bracket just being sytax sugar (the command `[` ignores the last argument if it's a closing bracket), so the line actually reads

```
if test :$RESULT != :0,0
```

It compares if the string `:$RESULT` equals to the string `:0,0`. The colon is prepended for the case that the variable `$RESULT` is empty. The line would look like the following if the colon was omitted and `$RESULT` was an empty string:

```
if test  != 0,0
```

This would lead to an error, since `test` expects an argument before `!=`. An alternative would be to use quotes to indicate that there is an argument, which is an empty string:

```
if test "$RESULT" != 0,0
# Will become
if test "" != 0,0
```

The variation you posted is more portable, though.

Comment: Try `man bash` and search for the builtin command `test` for further info

Comment: Okay, I follow that, thanks! 

So is it actually comparing to the string "0,0"? I only ask as the variable result would never have that value!

I wondered if the 0,0 does something else. A blank string perhaps?

Comment: No, `0,0` is a string and the operator `!=` compares strings, so it checks if `$RESULT` is the string `0,0`. Try `man test`.

Comment: Just done some small tests and you are indeed absolutely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think the `:` is a common trick people use in case the variable is empty.

If it's empty, then the shell would have this:

```
if [  != 0,0 ]
```

which would be a syntax error. Putting the `:` in front means that if the variable is empty the shell has this:

```
if [ : != :0,0 ]
```

which is not a syntax error and would (correctly) report false.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you'll see an `x` used in the way that the colon is used in your example.

The preferred way to do this type of test in Bash is to use the double square bracket:

```
if [[ $RESULT != 0,0 ]]
```

The double bracket form allows more flexibility, improved readability, reduced need for escaping and quoting and a few more features. See [this page](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more information.

If you want to test numeric values, instead of strings or files, use the double parentheses:

```
if (( 3 + 4 > 6 ))
```