# Comparing strings for equality in ksh

Tags: bash, unix, shell, ksh

i am testing with the shell script below:

```
#!/bin/ksh -x


instance=`echo $1 | cut -d= -f2`
if [ $instance == "ALL" ]
then
echo "strings matched \n"
fi
```

It's giving this error in the if condition:

```
: ==: unknown test operator
```

is `==` really not the correct syntax to use?
I am running on the command line as below

```
test_lsn_2 INSTANCE=ALL
```

Could anybody please suggest a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Put double-quotes around '`$instance`' in `if` and try it again. Let me know if that work.

Comment: NO putting double quotes around ` $instance ` doesnt work:(

Comment: Which version of `ksh` was this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see that you are using ksh, but you added bash as a tag, do you accept a bash-related answer?
Using bash you can do it in these ways:

```
if [[ "$instance" == "ALL" ]]
if [ "$instance" = "ALL" ]
if [[ "$instance" -eq "ALL" ]]
```

See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html) for more on that.

Comment: thanks for the reply monte. as andre miller said == is not working = is working.i will accept ur answer but also +1 for andre

Comment: I think the third option is not a good idea. AFAIK, -eq is for integer comparison, not strings.

Answer (score 17):

To compare strings you need a single =, not a double. And you should put it in double quotes in case the string is empty:

```
if [ "$instance" = "ALL" ]
then
    echo "strings matched \n"
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
if [ "$instance" = "ALL" ]; then
```

There were several mistakes:

1. You need double quotes around the variable to protect against the (unlikely) case that it's empty. In this case, the shell would see `if [  = "ALL" ]; then` which isn't valid.
2. Equals in the shell uses a single `=` (there is no way to assign a value in an `if` in the shell).

Answer (score 2):

```
totest=$1
case "$totest" in
  "ALL" ) echo "ok" ;;
  * ) echo "not ok" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I'va already answered a similar question. Basically the operator you need is `=` (not `==`) and the syntax breaks if your variable is empty (i.e. it becomes `if [ = ALL]`). Have a look at [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398994/shell-script-test/1399030#1399030) for details.