# shell script purpose of x in "x$VARIABLE"

Tags: unix, shell

I'm peeking through some shell scripts - what's the purpose of the x in the comarison shcu as

```
 if [ "x$USER" != "x$RUN_AS_USER" ]; then
        su - $RUN_AS_USER -c "$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh"
 else
        $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
 fi
```

Comment: Has already been asked and answered (even multiple times, I'd guess)

Comment: @soulmerge: links please

Comment: The link is visible to those that can close questions. I'll post them along with the comment from now on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398994/shell-script-test

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a trick to ensure you don't get an empty string in the substitution if one of the variables is empty. By putting `x` on both sides it's the same as just comparing the variables directly but the two sides will always be non-empty.

It's an old kludge which made more sense when scripts were written as:

```
if [ x$USER != x$RUN_AS_USER ]
```

There if you just had `$USER` and it were empty then you could end up with

```
if [  != root ]   # Syntax error
```

With the `x` you get this, which is better:

```
if [ x != xroot ]
```

However, when the variables are quoted the `x` is unnecessary since an empty string in quotes isn't removed entirely. It still shows up as a token. Thus

```
if [ "$USER" != "$RUN_AS_USER" ]   # Best
```

is the best way to write this. In the worst case with both variables empty you'd get this which is a valid statement:

```
if [ "" != "" ]
```

Comment: And it doesn't matter if '$USER' is '-f' because there are three arguments to test, so it must be an inequality and not a file test operation.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is related to odd-ball values, as Cristian Ciupitu suggests, but empty strings aren't the problem (at least, not when the value as a whole is quoted).  The issue is related to names that could be confused with operators to test (or '`[`'; on some systems, there really is a program `/bin/[`).  The POSIX standard has almost made this redundant, but consider what happens if '$USER' is '-f', '$RUN_AS_USER' is empty and the x's and quotes are not used.

```
if [ -f != ]
then : someone has a file called '!='
else : they don't have a file called '!='
fi
```

By using the quotes and the leading x, this sort of misinterpretation is avoided.

Answer (score 1):

If the variables are an empty string or uninitialized, *without* the `x` the `if` would look like this after the variable substitution:

```
 if [ != ]; then
```

and thus it would fail because the operands are missing. *With* the `x`, the `if` looks like this:

```
 if [ x != x]; then
```

which is syntactically valid.